# How to implement scaleBy using identityTransform in D3 v5?

Tags: d3.js

I need to mimic `transform.scaleBy()` using `identityTranform.translate().scale()`. I mean I need to simulate classic zoom behavior when user uses mouse wheel by external buttons.

It does scaling but I couldn't wrap my mind how to anchor it to the center of the graph. It is cornered to left top part of the chart.

```
const scaleByFactor = (f) => {
  const zt = zoomTransform(svgChart.node());

  const nk = f !== 1 ? (zt.k * f) : 1;
  const [mi, ma]= zoom1.scaleExtent();
  if (nk < mi || nk > ma) return;

  // I need help with this new coordinate, my canvas is way larger than visible area
  let nx = zt.x;

  const newIdentity = zoomIdentity.translate(nx, zt.y).scale(nk);

  svgChart.transition().duration(100).call(
    zoom1.transform,
    newIdentity
  );
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot provide the whole code.
If someone can me explain the theory part I'd really appreciate it.